# Is there a workaround for Ubiquity hanging on laptop-detect on a Xubuntu+Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: installation, wubi

I've run into https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/873791 when installing both XUbuntu and Ubuntu via Wubi on my laptop.  I was wondering if there was a workaround to avoid this hang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking to answer this, the answer is probably to try the alternate ISO.  Given I'm using Wubi, and the alternate ISO isn't supported through it and I don't have a working CD drive the answer for me is no, there isn't a workaround.