# Does this non-USB non-CD install process work for Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I found an article from 2007 on how to install Linux without using a USB stick or a CD at http://www.instantfundas.com/2007/08/install-any-linux-distro-directly-from.html.  I was wondering if anyone could tell me whether this still works, given it's five years old.  For starters I found that the initrd.gz file doesn't seem to exist but a initrd.lz file does.

Edit: And when I do try it, I get an "Error 21: Linux kernal must be loaded before initrd".

Comment: It might be better to ask how to do what that howto says here so we have something up to date.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that it will not work. That tutorial is for Windows and if you are running windows you are going to have better luck with wubi.

You download the wubi.exe from here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer

You run the wubi.exe like any other application and the installer will download the iso and install Ubuntu.

For additional information on wubi see

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi

Comment: I would love to use Wubi, but http://askubuntu.com/questions/97462/is-there-a-workaround-for-https-bugs-launchpad-net-ubuntu-source-ubiquity-bu explains why I'm not using Wubi given no one appears to know a workaround.

Comment: Nasty bug. You are going to run into that bug no matter how you boot the iso. Can you boot the laptop from a usb or cd ?

Comment: It doesn't support booting from USB (too old) and the CD drive is defunct (too old).

Comment: You should start a question with a better description of your problem and the specifics of your hardware. How much RAM ? Your best bet may be to use grub2 to directly boot the desktop.iso. You can then partition the hard drive manually and install using chroot. The details would be moderately technical. See: http://ansi.23-5.eu/2011/10/21/howto-boot-iso-images-via-grub2-with-ubuntu/ and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot . You perform a minimal install with debootstrap, then chroot and install ubuntu-desktop and a kernel, then re-configure grub to boot the debootstrap.